# I want camera permission to need to be granted only one time in a video networking - platform - issues with ios and safari

Tags: ios, safari, tokbox, agora.io, video-conferencing

I want to be able to enable a user on a video networking web platform to only need to grant camera permission one time, and be able to have separate video chats with multiple users.Part of the 'event" will have multiple one to one video chats. There is a one to one video chat with one user. it ends. there is another 1 to one video chat with another user. It ends, etc.... As it is this permission is needed to be granted for each separate video chat. I am having this issue primarily with ios on safari. I am having someone else build this web platform and the person is not able to solve this issue with the video plug in they are using. They claim it is an issue with mac devices that cannot grant permission to particular websites. But I know that this issue has been solved with other networking platforms. Can I accomplish this with tokbox (vonage)? Or please tell me what video platform to use and the specific way to accomplish this.  I am not a developer but will pass on exactly what you give me to my developer team. I am considering having the website be rebuilt with tokbox but first want to be sure that I can accomplish this. The website it being built with PHP but this issue is so sognificant that I might have it bilt from scratch in whatever way is needed. Thank you very much!!!! I know this issue is solveable as I've seen this on other platforms - Zoom and other video networking platforms like remo.. thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The Agora web SDK requests the browser for camera and microphone permissions. Now remembering these permissions is done by the browser itself and not the JavaScript SDK.

As to answer how other platforms offer this is because those are native apps and not a mobile website. So they don't have to play by the rules of the browser. If you are interested in that, you can take a look at our IOS SDK.

https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/start_call_ios?platform=iOS